# Consuming org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream@ Mule

Tags: json, groovy, mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I've 2 json feeds in payload (using Gather), i planned on using a groovy script to make it into a single json (I expected something like:

```
{key:value}{key:value})
<scripting:transformer doc:name="Groovy">
        <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[return '{"data":['+payload.toString().replace("}{","},{"+']}']]></scripting:script>    
    </scripting:transformer>
```

(expected output: `{"data":[{key:value},{key:value}]}`

But i get:

```
{"data":[[org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream@102e37e, org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream@a569d1]]}
```

W/O groovy script:

```
[org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream@102e37e, org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream@a569d1]
```

an array of inputstream

I tried using byte array to string, and object to string but it doesnt work, I dont figure out how can i solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
payload.toString().replace("}{","},{")
```

with:

```
payload.collect { it.text }.join(',')
```

Explanation: `.text` deserializes an input stream to a string, so `payload.collect { it.text }` will yield a collection of strings. Then `join(',')` takes care of concatenating these strings, separating them with `,`

Comment: <collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter"/>
        <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
        <collection-aggregator failOnTimeout="true" doc:name="Collection Aggregator"/>
        <scripting:transformer doc:name="Groovy">
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[return '{"data":'+payload.toString()+'}']]></scripting:script>
        </scripting:transformer>

Comment: I love your solution @david-dossot i solved it this way, but im going to change it right now

Comment: @Armok if you loved his solution so much why wouldn't you up vote it